# How do I know if a variable in Django contains anything in it?

Tags: python, django

My views.py :

```
class PostView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'airapp/post_list.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = PostForm()
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-date')
    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
    friend, created = Friend.objects.get_or_create(current_user=request.user)
    friends = friend.users.all()

    args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts, 'users': users, 'friends' : friends}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

My post_list.html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Friends</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {% if **not friends.exists()** %}
    <p>You don't have any friends :( Add one!!</p>
    {% else %}
    {% for friend in friends %}
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}"><h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3></a>
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:change_friend' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="button">Remove Friend</button> </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way in which I can check whether friends actually contains anything? Because if it doesn't, I want to display something else ( which is pretty evident)

Comment: print(friends) and check your console!

Comment: Try [for ... empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## With the truthiness of a `QuerySet`

Well the *truthiness* of a `QuerySet` is whether it contains any elements, so you can check `if friends`. Like:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Friends</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {% if not friends %}
    <p>You don't have any friends :( Add one!!</p>
    {% else %}
    {% for friend in friends %}
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}"><h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3></a>
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:change_friend' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="button">Remove Friend</button> </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

In case the query is not yet made, Django will make the query, so given you want to iterate over the `QuerySet`, this is more efficient than an exists call, since it loads the results as well, in a single database query.

## With an `EXISTS` query

If you are however, *not* interested in using the queryset, but only want to look if the queryset has at least one element, you can use the `friends.exists()` call. Note that in Django templates, you do *not* add the brackets: in case an element is callable, Django will automatically call it:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Friends</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {% if not friends.exists %}
    <p>You don't have any friends :( Add one!!</p>
    {% else %}
    {% for friend in friends %}
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}"><h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3></a>
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:change_friend' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="button">Remove Friend</button> </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

(This will usually require a second query when you iterate over it, which is the case here).

## With a `for`-`empty` loop

Django templates also has a [**`{% for ...%}`-`{% empty %}`-`{% endfor %}`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) construct. One can use a `{% empty %}` template below the *body* of the `for` loop, and before the `{% endfor %}` that contains content that is displayed in case the `for` loop has no eleemnts, like:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Friends</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {% for friend in friends %}
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}"><h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3></a>
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:change_friend' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="button">Remove Friend</button> </a>
    {% empty %}
    <p>You don't have any friends :( Add one!!</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Friends</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {% if friends %}
    {% for friend in friends %}
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}"><h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3></a>
      <a href="{% url 'airapp:change_friend' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="button">Remove Friend</button> </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>You don't have any friends :( Add one!!</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```